# C++: Vector with coordinates. How to remove duplicates and all elements that lie between them

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector with my coordinates. What i am trying to do is to find if there are duplicates and remove all elements between them. 
The vector contains these coordinates. 
(0,0)
(0,1)
(0,0)
(0,-1)
(0,-2)
What i need to do is check the first element and find any duplicates and then remove all elements between them plus the duplicate. The output in this case would then be
(0,0)
(0,-1)
(0,-2)

This is my struct and how i put them in the vector.

```
struct Coordinate
{
 public:
 int x;
 int y;
 Coordinate(int valuex, int valuey) : x(valuex), y(valuey) {}
};

vector<Coordinate> coords;
coords.push_back(Coordinate(x, y));
```

Any hints or directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your *expected* behavior with : `((0,0), ..., (0,0), ... (0,0), ...)` ? Is the first "pair" wiped, leaving neither, so the third is retained? Are all three wiped (and in so doing, wiping *both* partitions?)? Or what about `(0,0), ... (0,1), (0,0), ... (0,1) ...)` ? Once the first partition (bracketed by  `(0,0)`) is wiped, is the second (bracketed by `(0,1)`) no longer considered?

Comment: The first one would be kept but the the rest wiped. As in if i had ((0,0),(0,1),(0,0),(0,-1),(0,0),(1,0)) i would have ((0,0),(1,0)) left.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? The live example: http://ideone.com/IHLg3t

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>

struct Coordinate
{
    public:
        int x;
        int y;

        Coordinate(int valuex, int valuey) : x(valuex), y(valuey) {}
};

bool sortcomp(const Coordinate &a, const Coordinate &b)
{
    return (a.x < b.x) || (a.y < b.y);
}

bool compare(const Coordinate &a, const Coordinate &b)
{
    return (a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y);
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::vector<Coordinate> &v)
{
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end() - 1; ++it)
        std::cout<<"("<<it->x<<", "<<it->y<<"), ";

    std::cout<<"("<<v[v.size() - 1].x<<", "<<v[v.size() - 1].y<<")";
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<Coordinate> v = {{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,0}, {0,-1}, {0,0}, {1,0}};

    std::sort(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), sortcomp);
    v.erase(std::unique(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), compare), v.end());

    if (v.size() > 2)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 1; i < v.size() - 1; ++i)
        {
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    std::cout<<v;
}
```

Comment: This is very close yes but not exactly. As you can see here http://ideone.com/VuKbV9 the output is((0,0),(0,1)) but should be ((0,0),(0,-1),(0,-2)). Also the for loop in main should say .erase(v.end() - i); ?